# Where can I download NDVI or landsat images of south china that isn't in an .img file format

Tags: data, erdas-imagine, ndvi, hdf

Everything i seem to find is an hdf file and i can't open it in erdas. so is there a way to convert it to open in erdas or do i need to find somewhere else, earth explorer and glovis are the two places i've tried so far.

Comment: unlike modis, landsat are not distributed in hdf as far as I know. Furthermore erdas is supposed to read hdf. otherwise you could try gdal (free open source software).

Comment: You should be able to export hdf in ERDAS. What version are you using ?  You can try do it in ArcGIS as I have done them in the past. it is not easy as you think but I have done both ways.

Comment: What version of Erdas are you using? I agree with the others that Erdas should have no problem handling HDF files.

Comment: no worries fellas. got it working